# How to add lag and lead to each observations for more variables excluding NAs within data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, window-functions

I have a data.table similar to this:

```r
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(id = LETTERS[1:6], x = 1:6, y = 2:3) 
> mydt
   id x y
1:  A 1 2
2:  B 2 3
3:  C 3 2
4:  D 4 3
5:  E 5 2
6:  F 6 3
```

I would like to replace the value columns with adding the lag and lead to each observation (i.e. `x[-1] + x + x[1]`). I can do something like this with the amazing `shift()` feature.

```r
cols <- c('x', 'y')
mydt[
    ,
    (cols) := shift(.SD, 1) + .SD + shift(.SD, 1, type = 'lead'),
    .SDcols = cols
][]
   id  x  y
1:  A NA NA
2:  B  6  7
3:  C  9  8
4:  D 12  7
5:  E 15  8
6:  F NA NA
```

But this introduces NAs for rows where there is no lead/lag value. How can I modify the calculation to use the available two values only for these rows (like `na.rm = TRUE`)? So that the output would be

```r
   id  x  y
1:  A  3  5
2:  B  6  7
3:  C  9  8
4:  D 12  7
5:  E 15  8
6:  F 11  5
```

I tried using `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)` instead of the `+` operator but that gives error: `Error in sum(shift(.SD, 1), .SD, shift(.SD, 1, type = "lead"), na.rm = TRUE) :
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument`.

I also tried the following but that apparently gives something else as a result.

```r
mydt[
    ,
    (cols) := lapply(
        .SD, 
        function(x) sum(shift(x, 1), x, shift(x, 1, type = 'lead'), na.rm = TRUE)
    ),
    .SDcols = cols
][]
   id   x  y
1:  A 126 90
2:  B 126 90
3:  C 126 90
4:  D 126 90
5:  E 126 90
6:  F 126 90
```

Comment: perhaps `mydt[, (cols):=lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, fill=0)+x+shift(x, type="lead", fill=0)) , .SDcols= cols]`

Comment: @akrun You can post an answer as I'm not going to anyway. Nice try @jan btw, you are making nice progress in `data.table` :)

Comment: thanks, I was so close... please post as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @DavidArenburg It's okay.  YOu first came up with the idea, so you can post it.

Comment: In that case I would suggest @jan answer himself as he did most of the work. I'm not going to post either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun and @DavidArenburg pointed out, the `shift` function has a `fill` parameter which solves the issue.

```r
cols <- c('total_open', 'total_send')
mydt[
    ,
    (cols) := shift(.SD, 1, fill = 0) + .SD + shift(.SD, 1, type = 'lead', fill = 0),
    .SDcols = cols
][]
   id  x y
1:  A  3 5
2:  B  6 7
3:  C  9 8
4:  D 12 7
5:  E 15 8
6:  F 11 5
```